# Sphering data with SVD components of covariance matrix

Tags: svd

[The Elements of Statistical Learning](http://books.google.com/books?id=tVIjmNS3Ob8C&lpg=PA116&ots=ELDeO7K3V2&dq=elements%20of%20statistical%20learning%20sphering&pg=PA113#v=onepage&q&f=false) says on page 113:

> Sphere the data with respect to the common covariance estimates $\hat{\Sigma}$:
>   $X^* \leftarrow D^{-1/2}U^TX$ where  $\hat{\Sigma} = UDU^T$. The common covariance estimate of $X^*$ will now be the identity.

Can someone help me understand why $X^* \leftarrow D^{-1/2}U^TX$ spheres the data?

Comment: Have you tried working out what the covariance of $X^{\star}$ will be?

Answer (score 9):

I think I figured out the answer after seeing cardinal's suggestion and reading the Wikipedia page on [whitening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitening_transformation).

> $cov(X^*) = E[X^*X^{*T}]$
>
> $= E[D^{-\frac{1}{2}}U^TXX^TUD^{-\frac{1}{2}T}]$

$D^{-\frac{1}{2}T} = D^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ because it's a diagonal matrix

> $= D^{-\frac{1}{2}}U^TE[XX^T]UD^{-\frac{1}{2}}$
>
> $= D^{-\frac{1}{2}}U^T\hat{\Sigma}UD^{-\frac{1}{2}}$
>
> $= D^{-\frac{1}{2}}U^TUDU^TUD^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

The $U^TU = 1$ because U's have unit length.

> $= D^{-\frac{1}{2}}DD^{-\frac{1}{2}}$
>
> $= I$